# Why flink can't support RichFunction on Reduce/Fold/Aggregate now?

Tags: streaming, apache-flink

I've searched `RichAggregateFunction` in github repository, just found below.

`.aggregate() does not support [[RichAggregateFunction]], since the reduce function is used internally in a [[org.apache.flink.api.common.state.AggregatingState]].`

Is that mean Flink can't merge elements' state in group window?

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you mean by "merge" here, you would generally do that work in the [ProcessWindowFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/windowing/ProcessWindowFunction.html) when you call `stream.aggregate`. The PWF would be your second parameter and it will receive the aggregation which you can perform additional operations on.

If you need to combine the aggregated elements together in some other way you can take the stream that comes out of the `aggregate` and do additional operations on them (such as a `ProcessFunction`).